# INSERT INTO and insert NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Update:
This question has no value and can be deleted. The syntax shown in the question actually works well and is likely the best approach.

I'd like to insert NULL into one column as part of a "select into". In the example below, I try  to copy columns a and b from table_1 to table_2, and in the same query, insert NULL into table_2.c

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (a, b, c)
    SELECT a, b, NULL
    FROM table_1
```

But I get `ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or near "NULL"`.

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: `SELECT a, b, NULL AS c`

Comment: Perfect, works great, thanks for the prompt assistance!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: The added column alias serves no purpose whatsoever in this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonsense. Your statement is syntactically correct.
None of the suggestions here are necessary. The error you report should not occur.

Also, [`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) (like you wrote in error) is an unrelated command - the use of which is discouraged in favor of `CREATE TABLE AS`.

Typically, you can just omit columns that shall be `NULL` from the target list - unless a different default value is set for the column. But it's typically bad style to omit the target column list altogether (exceptions apply).

```sql
INSERT INTO table_2 (a, b)
SELECT a, b
FROM   table_1;
```

If column `table_2.c` has no different `DEFAULT` value in the table definition, it defaults to `NULL`. To be precise:

- [How to use default value of data type as column default?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212253/3684)

Shorter; but there is nothing wrong with your original query. In fact, it's the best way.

Comment: Hey Ermin, you're right. Trying it again, my original example works fine. I must have made another unrelated mistake. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

Comment: @Erwin thanks for pointing out, you're totally right. In the late hours I simply misunderstood the issue and my answer isn't very meaningful. I'll delete it. +1